# Multi-line fitting on a graph and calculating the position of the intersection points of the lines

Tags: python, curve-fitting, multiline

Using an input dataset, I have drawn a graph similar to the one below:
[figure_1: Log-Log plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/649DK.png)
and I want fitting multi lines like below:
[figure_2: multi line fitting that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QL3R.png)
then calculate the position of the intersection points of this lines. I check it by this python code but this is not work, please help me.

```
dfn=pd.read_csv('input.csv')
x=dfn['X']
y=dfn['Y']
plt.scatter(np.log(x),np.log(y))
num_lines=3
for i in range(num_lines):
    coef=np.polyfit(np.log(x),np.log(y),1)
    poly1d_fn=np.poly1d(coef)
    plt.plot(np.log(x),poly1d_fn(np.log(x)),'r--')
intersection_points=[]
for i in range(num_lines):
    for j in range(i+1, num_lines):
        coef1=np.polyfit(np.log(x),np.log(y),1)
        coef2=np.polyfit(np.log(x),np.log(y),1)
        poly1d_fn1=np.poly1d(coef1)
        poly1d_fn2=np.poly1d(coef2)
        intersection_point=(np.exp((poly1d_fn2-poly1d_fn1).roots),np.exp(poly1d_fn1((poly1d_fn2-poly1d_fn1).roots)))
        intersection_points.append(intersection_point)
intersection_df=pd.DataFrame(intersection_points,columns=['X','Y'])
intersection_df.to_csv('intersection_points.csv',index=False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The example code below identifies where the lines intersect. You need to specify `x_orig`, `y_orig`, and `n_lines`. The code takes the log of the data and determines the intersections.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#
# Synthetic data
#

# Replace with your original data: x_orig = dfn['X'], y_orig = dfn['Y']
x_orig = np.exp( np.linspace(3.75, 5.75, 150) )
y_orig = np.exp( (np.sin(0.1 * np.pi * np.log(x_orig)**2/3) + 1) * 4 )

#Take logs of the data
x = np.log(x_orig)
y = np.log(y_orig)

#Plot the data
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 3))
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='|', s=90)
ax_lims = ax.axis()

#
# Fit lines
#
n_lines = 3

#Divide the x range into n_lines segments
points_per_line = len(x) // n_lines

coefs_per_line = []
for index in range(n_lines):
    start = points_per_line * index
    end = start + points_per_line
    
    #If this is the last line,
    # Use up all the remaining points
    is_last_line = (index == n_lines - 1)
    if is_last_line:
        end = len(x)
        
    x_segment = x[start:end]
    y_segment = y[start:end]
    
    #Fit line, and store coefficients
    slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x_segment, y_segment, deg=1)
    coefs_per_line.append((slope, intercept))
    
    #Plot longer lines to show them intersecting
    pad = 10
    x_longer = x[start - pad if index > 0 else start : end if is_last_line else end + pad]
    ax.plot(x_longer, slope * x_longer + intercept, 'r-', linewidth=2)
    
    if index == 0:
        ax.legend(['data', 'linear fits'])

#
# Determine where adjacent lines intersect
#
intersections = []
for index in range(n_lines - 1):
    #Get the coefficients for a line, and the line next to it
    slope_a, intercept_a = coefs_per_line[index]
    slope_b, intercept_b = coefs_per_line[index + 1]
    
    #Solve for the x where line_a = line_b
    #No solution when they're parallell (slope_a = slope_b)
    if slope_a == slope_b:
        intersection_x = np.nan
    else:
        intersection_x = (intercept_a - intercept_b) / (slope_b - slope_a)
    intersections.append(intersection_x)

#
# Finally, add lines showing the locations of the intersections
#
print('Intersections between adjacent lines:')
for i, intersection in enumerate(intersections):
    ax.vlines(intersection, ymin=y.min() - 1, ymax=y.max() + 1, color='k', linestyle=':')
    print(f'  lines {i + 1} & {i + 2} intersect at',
          f'log(x_orig)={intersection:>4.2f} -> x_orig={np.exp(intersection):>5.1f}', )

ax.axis(ax_lims)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this code didn't work true for my database. My database should be plot as log-log , so i enter np.log(x) and np.log(y) and I replace with your initial data but fit lines shows a mess.

Comment: I've now updated the code to work when taking the log of the original data.

Comment: Thank you I found that the 'n_lines' should increase to find the best fit for my data. very thanks for your help.